# How to retrieve data from SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a web application.  When the user clicks on a button in my web application, I'd like to retrieve data from SharePoint on behalf of the user.  I have read quite a few articles on SharePoint but I'm still not sure how to proceed.  Should I create a provider hosted SharePoint App and use the SharePointREST API? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a Provider to use the SharePoint Rest Services.

Quoting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022(v=office.15).aspx :

> One advantage of using REST is that you don’t have to add references to any SharePoint 2013 libraries or client assemblies. Instead, you make HTTP requests to the appropriate endpoints to retrieve or update SharePoint entities, such as webs, lists, and list items. See Get started with the SharePoint 2013 REST service for a thorough introduction to the SharePoint 2013 REST interface and its architecture.

Inside the page you will find videos and code examples that will help you to connect and execute operations.

Answer (score 0):

It's Correct. Data in SharePoint is Stored in Lists or Libraries (to files).

You can use the Client Object Model, to get data remotely from a SharePoint Server (on-premise or Online). The Client Object Model can be used through Assemblies (DLL files) or REST services provided by SharePoint. Generally you should know the location of the data you are going to get, that is, as I initially mentioned, the data in SharePoint are stored in Lists or Libraries, therefore you must know the name of the List or Library Additional Site or Sub-site of the List or Library is.

If the name of the list where the information is stored is "employees" and the HR website, the URL could be formed as follows:
http://spserver.company.com/HR/Employees
For REST services, simply complete URL of the list you want to see, so that you retrieve the information from the list. If you want to apply filters, sorting, to retrieve specific columns, you must do it through CAML queries which the add on REST service call.

Comment: How about authentication? I forgot to mention that the SharePoint instances are owned by our customers.  Do I need to create a SharePoint App and use OAuth for authentication? I read about the REST API and it seemed pretty straight forward.  However, I don't know what I need to set up (e.g. authentication) before I can make the REST calls on behalf of a user.

Comment: If you have access to configure SharePoint application you can configure as basic authentication (taking into account security measures), you can send the credentials to call the service, for this you must add in the header of the request to the service.

Comment: WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"https://sps.companyy.com/HR/Employees");
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:password"));

Comment: Your solution should work.  What if I can't ask for the password? Do I have to use OAuth then? Do you know what I need to do if I choose to use OAuth? Thank you.